# NFS NAS disc space only being given to one sub-directory

Tags: linux, storage, nfs

I am having a problaem with the disc space on my 3TB NAS seeming to be split between sub-directories outside my control. No quotas have been set, and when they fill up the errors are not "quota exceeded" but "not enough disk space for this operation". After some investigation and experiment I am at a loss as to how to change this.

The device is an old WD MyCloud that I am now managing directly via the shell, because of the nightmare of getting it to work with Windows 10 (because of Microsofts SMB lockdown and the lack of a real solution from WD even with the latest firmware).

I tried changing the SMB .conf files but to no avail so instead am running it as an NFS server. This works OK when mounted as a disc drive though am having trouble getting it to be stable as a network location. The underlying system is Debian Linux running on an ARM-based machine with 256MD RAM and a 3TB disc.

Looking at the top level /nfs folder, it claims to have only 1.9GB of disc space. The vast majority of the space is sitting under a /nfs/Music folder.

Running df -f from the terminal gets me:

[image: du -f results]

As I understand it, this shows the c. 1.9 GB showing up on a 'root' storage device and the vast majority showing up as 'sda4' mounted under the /nfs/Music directory.

I have no idea how this happened or how to change it so that all the various directories under the NFS directory will share the space according need. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't post links to information - post the information directly in your question.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I am confused - I haven't posted any links to information - I have described my problem and included a screen shot of the 'df' results. 

I have shared the background and my best understanding of the underlying problem. And explained I have no idea how to resolve it and hoped for answers relating ot it.

So I don't understand what the issue you are raising is.

Comment: I think maybe he was referring to the screenshot of the df output, instead of the output itself.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchulman.